# nodeJS - fix SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: node.js

I've used in past this [npm repo](https://github.com/Dobby89/guerrillamail-api), it's a simple wrapper around guerrilla mail API. I've added it in past to my projects by using the ´require()´ function without any problem. At the moment I want to use the same library inside a node CLI script that I'm creating but I always get this error:

```js
/Users/b/Sites/Te/node_modules/guerrillamail-api/src/index.js:1
import axios from 'axios';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at compileFunction (<anonymous>)
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:353:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1039:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1073:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1138:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:989:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:829:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1013:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:93:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/b/Sites/Te/followBot.js:9:23)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1109:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1138:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:989:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:829:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

I's very strange, is there any solution to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `"type": "module"` to your `package.json` file.

Comment: I've ended up with a temporary solution. I've converted the original library syntax to use `require()` instead of `import` and replaced the `export default` with `module.exports`. Now seems working fine, thank you for the help.